# How to draw polyline using gMap and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-gmap

I would like to use [gMap](https://github.com/fridek/gmap) jQuery plugin in my project. I succesfully display Google map, I can display some markers, but I cannot find any way how to draw polyline.

I have this JS code:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  var data = {
    'latitude': 0.000000,
    'longitude': -180.000000,
    'zoom': 3,
    'maptype': "terrain",
  };
  var gps_coordinates = {
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    path: [
      {'latitude':37.772323,'longitude':-122.214897},
      {'latitude':21.291982,'longitude':-157.821856},
      {'latitude':-18.142599,'longitude':178.431000},
      {'latitude':-27.467580,'longitude':153.027892}
    ]
  };

  $('#map').gMap(data);
  $('#map').gMap("Polyline", gps_coordinates);
});
```

In [gMap documentation](http://www.smashinglabs.pl/gmap/documentation) is this note:

> You can also use some of internal gmap functions.

So I suppose, I can use `google.maps.Polyline` function to draw a polyline. But how?

Comment: Also it looks to me like you're confusing latitude (goes between +90 to -90) and longitude (goes between +180 to -180). Testing my code with your data gives odd results.  Switching latitude and longitude in your paths array looks much nicer :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake in the code. I'll fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the gMap plugin.  However if I was doing this just using Google Maps API 3, I'd do something like this:

```
var homeLatlng= new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: homeLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var pathLatLng;

var paths = [
      {'latitude':37.772323,'longitude':-122.214897},
      {'latitude':21.291982,'longitude':-157.821856},
      {'latitude':-18.142599,'longitude':178.431000},
      {'latitude':-27.467580,'longitude':153.027892}
    ];

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    pathLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(paths[i].latitude, paths[i].longitude);

    path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [homeLatlng, pathLatLng],
        strokeColor: "##FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        geodesic: true,
        map: map
    });
}
```

this map draws curved lines indicating the true shortest route between two destinations.  If you just want straight lines, set the geodesic attribute to false

Comment: Thank you. At the end, I used your code and not gMap pluging. It looks like gMap is created only for displaying map and markers.

Comment: The Google Maps API is so simple, I'm not sure that gMap gives any real benefit for most people.

Answer (score 0):

Gmap has an overlays extension (jquery.ui.map.overlays.js) which allows you to add shapes like polylines.

Here is an example (avlMarkers is an array of LatLng's):

```
var colour = '#0000FF';
var polyline = {
    path: avlMarkers,
    strokeColor: colour,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
 };
 $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Polyline', polyline);
```